# Pod not listed in Pods file but it installing on pod install command

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking

Following is the screenshot of **pods** file which does not include AFNetworking library. When I run command `pod install` in my terminal it installed AFNetworking library version 3.0.1. I am not able to understand why this happens.

[image]

Moreover, I also checked **Podfile.lock** file. I can check AFNetworking listed in this file. See the following screenshot:

[image]

I do not want to include AFNetworking in my project.

Comment: It can be dependency of AFNetworking pod from your listed pod list.

Comment: @PratikSodha:Would you tell me how to remove it?

Comment: AFOAuth2Manager is extension of AFNetworking So, on installing AFOAuth2Manager AFNetworking also install automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Check **`.podspec`** file for all listed pods. It's mentioned
>   **`.dependency`** for in pod specification file.

Check in your case *AFOAuth2Manager* pod specification in
**AFOAuth2Manager.podspec** their dependency of **AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~>3.0'**.

[image]

**Example -** [Check here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager/blob/master/AFOAuth2Manager.podspec)

Comment: how to fix this iisue?

Answer (score 0):

If your listed any pod having dependency on other pod then it will get install .
This will be mentioned in git repository comment .